# Compute Pointwise Multiplication by hand

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

How could we compute the pointwise multiplication of two vectors?
In example:

```
A = [1 2 3]'
```

What is the pointwise multiplication of A.^2? (like computational programs using)

In short: what steps should be take to convert:
 `A = [1 2 3]' to A^2 = [1 4 9]'`

Answer (score 0):

$A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3\}$

$A\cdot A= A^2 = \{a_1\cdot a_1, a_2\cdot a_2, a_3\cdot a_3\}$

In your example:

$A.A = A^2 = \{1^2,2^2,3^2\} = \{1,4,9\}$